# How can I prevent my app from being vulnerable to android-ssl-bypass

Tags: android, ssl

I have come across the android-ssl-bypass https://github.com/iSECPartners/android-ssl-bypass/blob/master/README.md tool. How would I be able to prevent my app from being vulnerable to this or some other attack?

Comment: "How would I be able to prevent my app from being vulnerable to this" -- don't distribute the app. This particular technique involves the use of the SDK tools (debugger, emulator, etc.). You cannot prevent people from using those tools, and you cannot prevent people from getting your app if you distribute it. Even if this specific attack did not exist, the attacker could simply modify your app to employ a proxy. "or some other attack" -- that would depend entirely upon what the "some other attack" actually is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within scope as defined in the Help Center. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. I'm not sure where the best place is to point you to. I'm not sure because you need to understand what pen testers and reversers do to attack your app. Perhaps [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *"How can I prevent my app..."* - the short answer is to move sensitive code and data out of the attackers hands. That means sensitive code and data must reside on the server you control, and not the device an attacker controls.